# What is the purpose of felix.xml?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

In some projects which are built by Maven and related to OSGi and the OSGi Container Felix, there is a file called felix.xml. What is this file good for?

Its content mostly looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
 <id>all</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.main</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</source>
      <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.build.directory}/felix.jar</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.build.directory}/config.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

Examples:
https://www.assembla.com/code/appdapter/subversion/nodes/trunk/maven/Appdapter_OSGi/src/main/assembly/felix.xml?rev=32

https://trac.neo4j.org/browser/laboratory/users/akollegger/neo4j-osgi-hello-cmd/src/main/assembly/felix.xml?rev=7595

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. `felix.xml` is created by NetBeans when creating a new OSGi-Bundle-project. This file is needed to make the OSGi bundle runnable inside Apache Felix.
So if it's not needed to run the OSGi bundle, the file can savely be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, those xml files created by netbeans don't have much documentation on them.